# Weekly Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I want to create a weekly calendar which display the current week and has two buttons nextweek and previousweek. Im able to move to the nextweek, but Im struggling with previousweek button. Need some suggestions for the same. I have used HTML, CSS and Javascript. Im struggling with the logic of previousweek button.

[image]

```js
const date = new Date();

function renderCalendar(lastdayofweek)
  {
  var lastofweek = lastdayofweek;
  date.setDate(1);

  const monthDays     = document.querySelector(".days");
  var   lastDay       = new Date( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
  const prevLastDay   = new Date( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0 ).getDate();
  const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();
  const lastDayIndex  = new Date( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0 ).getDay();
  const nextDays      = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;

  const months = 
    [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'
    , 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
    ];

  document.querySelector(".date h1").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];
  document.querySelector(".date p").innerHTML  = new Date().toDateString();

  let days  = '' 
    , count = 0
    ;
  if (lastofweek+7 >= lastDay)
    {
    for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--)
      {
      days      += `<div class="prev-date">${prevLastDay - x + 1}</div>`;
      count      = count+1;
      lastofweek = prevLastDay - x + 1;
      lastDay    = lastofweek;
      }
    }

  const nxtDay = 7 - count - 1;

  if (lastofweek == undefined)
    {
    for (let i = 1; i <= nxtDay+1; i++)
      {
      if (i === new Date().getDate() && date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) 
        {
        days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
        } 
      else 
        {
        days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
        lastDayOfWeek = i;
        }
      count = count+1;
      monthDays.innerHTML = days;
      }
    }
  else
    {
    if (lastofweek+1 > lastDay)
      {
      lastofweek = 0;
      }   
    var forCount = 0;

    for (let i = lastofweek+1; i <= lastofweek+7; i++)
      {
      if(lastDay >= i && forCount <= nxtDay)
        {
        if (i === new Date().getDate() && date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth())
          {
          days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
          } 
        else 
          {
          days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
          lastDayOfWeek = i;
          }
        count    = count+1;
        forCount = forCount + 1;
        monthDays.innerHTML = days;
        }
      } 
    }

  if (count < 7)
    {
    for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) 
      {
      days += `<div class="next-date">${j}</div>`;
      monthDays.innerHTML = days;
      }
    }
  }


document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => 
  {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth());
  renderCalendar();
  });

const lastDay = new Date( date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0 ).getDate();

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () =>
  {
  if(lastDayOfWeek+7 > lastDay)
    {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
    renderCalendar(lastDayOfWeek);
    }
  else
    {
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    renderCalendar(lastDayOfWeek);
    }
  });

renderCalendar();
```

```css
* {
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  font-family : "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  }
html {
  font-size : 62.5%;
  }
.container {
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100vh;
  background-color : #12121f;
  color            : #eee;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  align-items      : center;
  }
.calendar {
  width            : 45rem;
  height           : 52rem;
  background-color : #222227;
  box-shadow       : 0 0.5rem 3rem #00000066;
  }
.month {
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 12rem;
  background-color : #167e56;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : space-between;
  align-items      : center;
  padding          : 0 2rem;
  text-align       : center;
  text-shadow      : 0 0.3rem 0.5rem #00000080;
  }
.month i {
  font-size : 2.5rem;
  cursor    : pointer;
  }
.month h1 {
  font-size      : 3rem;
  font-weight    : 400;
  text-transform : uppercase;
  letter-spacing : 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom  : 1rem;
  }
.month p {
  font-size : 1.6rem;
  }
.weekdays {
  width       : 100%;
  height      : 5rem;
  padding     : 0 0.4rem;
  display     : flex;
  align-items : center;
  }
.weekdays div {
  font-size       : 1.5rem;
  font-weight     : 400;
  letter-spacing  : 0.1rem;
  width           : calc(44.2rem / 7);
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  text-shadow : 0 0.3rem 0.5rem #00000080;
  }
.days {
  width     : 100%;
  display   : flex;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  padding   : 0.2rem;
  }
.days div {
  font-size       : 1.4rem;
  margin          : 0.3rem;
  width           : calc(40.2rem / 7);
  height          : 5rem;
  display         : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items     : center;
  text-shadow     : 0 0.3rem 0.5rem #00000080;
  transition      : background-color 0.2s;
  }
.days div:hover:not(.today) {
  background-color : #262626;
  border           : 0.2rem solid #777;
  cursor           : pointer;
  }
.today {
  background-color : #167e56;
  }
/* --- --- --- 
.prev-date,
.next-date {
  opacity : 0.5;
  } 
--- --- --- */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" >
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" >

<input type="hidden" name="dates" class="dates" value="<?= $dates ?>" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="month">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
      <div class="date">
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="weekdays">
      <div>Sun</div>
      <div>Mon</div>
      <div>Tue</div>
      <div>Wed</div>
      <div>Thu</div>
      <div>Fri</div>
      <div>Sat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="days"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```